# Can I hide the Adobe floating toolbar when showing a PDF in browser?

Tags: pdf, browser, adobe, itext

I am generating a PDF document and displaying it in a Web browser (current version of IE is most important target).  I want to suppress the floating toolbar (see below) that appears and disappears depending on mouse movement.

Is there a way to suppress this? I can control the PDF document (it's built using itextpdf), as well as the Url.

[image: Adobe Reader floating toolbar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't possible.
Read the answer by Leonard Rosenthol (Adobe's PDF architect) on the iText mailing list: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/55112/focus=55120

Since version X of Adobe Reader, there is a new mode called "Read Mode",
which is the default viewing mode when you open a PDF in a web browser.
In "Read Mode" you can find a semi-transparent floating toolbar containing
basic reading controls, such as page navigation, print and zoom.

Unchecking "Display in Read Mode by Default" can be done from *Edit > Preferences > Internet*
in Adobe Reader X but it there is no way to disable "read mode" programmatically.

Answer (score 10):

I think that is the preference of the user.

What you can do is to add `#toolbar=0` to the end of the URL.

For example,

```
http://DOMAIN/FILE_NAME.pdf#toolbar=0
```

Something you might want to do is:

```
<embed src="MyFile.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0&navpanes=1" width="530" height="300" />
```

For details of parameters, please visit [PDF Open Parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf).

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. What is it expected to do, if this is a user preference?

Comment: The parameter is located at [PDF Open Parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf). You can do something like:
`<embed src="MyFile.pdf#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0&navpanes=1" width="530" height="300" />`

Comment: Brilliant, just what I needed!

Answer (score -4):

This the way:

myPdfView.put_src("D:\Recomendations.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0");

You are welcome...