# hide toolbar of pdf in AxAcroPDF

Tags: c#, .net, axacropdf

Hi i am showing pdf document using C#. i just want to show pdf document without showing tool bar.please answer anyone.this is my code

```
        axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
        this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Chinna\Desktop\Sample.pdf");
```

setShowtoolbar(fasle) property is not working[image]

i want to hide this toolbar in my pdf document

Answer (score 4):

you should load file first then `setShowToolbar` to false

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Chinna\Desktop\Sample.pdf");
axAcroPDF1.src = @"C:\Users\Chinna\Desktop\Sample.pdf";
axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
axAcroPDF1.Show();
```

Comment: Hi @dotctor. its working in my application but its not working in other application

Comment: what is your application? what is others application? what is not working?

Comment: in my application i just load a file directly.in other application i created a pdf document using itextsharp then display in axAcroPDF1.

Comment: this is another application code                      axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filepath);
axAcroPDF1.src = filepath;
axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
axAcroPDF1.Show();

Comment: Sorry its working in my system but not in some systems .i cant find the answer, anyone please answer for this..

Comment: what is the difference between your system and other systems? that's a whole new question

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750725/can-i-hide-the-adobe-floating-toolbar-when-showing-a-pdf-in-browser