# Blocking floating toolbar options for PDF in kiosk mode

Tags: pdf, browser, adobe, toolbar

I'm running a PDF-based exhibit on a public touchscreen and I don't want users to be able to execute any of the floating toolbar options (print, save, exit read mode). Using URL parameters (toolbar=0, navpanes=0,etc.), putting my browser in kiosk mode, and disabling read mode in Reader preferences work…until they don't. Let me explain:

Because my PDF links to an HTML page (which itself iframes a PDF), going back and forth between the PDF and HTML inevitably causes the floating toolbar to reappear.

I've just about given up on ever truly getting rid of the floating toolbar. If that' off the table, then I want to thwart the toolbar's functionality. So, when a user clicks on the A symbol to exit, they don't crash my kiosk/full screen mode.

[Note: Previous similar exchange on this didn't answer for me, since the effect of disabling Read Mode isn't persistent when the user moves from PDF to HTML and back-again: [Can I hide the Adobe floating toolbar when showing a PDF in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750725/can-i-hide-the-adobe-floating-toolbar-when-showing-a-pdf-in-browser])