# ¿How can I show a pdf on primefaces or html component without a toolbar that let the user download the document?Pdf view only

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, jakarta-ee, iframe, primefaces

Please help. I have the requirement to show a pdf but without the toolbar that lets the user download the document, so the pdf can be view only.

I tried using "#toolbar=0;" but didnt get anything. I attach my code

Comment: If you allow to view the PDF in browser, you can't prevent a user knowledgable to IT from storing that PDF locally. Hiding toolbars is just cosmitic. Generally it's user preference whether or not to show the toolbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide the Adobe floating toolbar when showing a PDF in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750725/can-i-hide-the-adobe-floating-toolbar-when-showing-a-pdf-in-browser)

Comment: So maybe it is impossible to do that programatically. By this time I am trying to encrypt the document so the user can´t print it, but I am getting an error too,I will make the proper question soon.